# How do I use all processor cores during execution?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm writing a threaded program in [Rust](http://rust-lang.org).

[Go](http://golang.org) has an environment variable `GOMAXPROCS` which is used by the Go compiler to use the maximum amount of processor cores during execution. I found the `RTRACEMAXPROCS` parameter [here](https://github.com/Byron/rust-tracer/blob/5d064030f9716dcb2dd24f1091d1de09d225d19b/README.md) after many searches, but I can't find any documentation for this.

Is the `RTRACEMAXPROCS` parameter the same as `GOMAXPROCS` for Rust?

Is it good practice to use over 800K threads in single process or should I use multiple processes?

Comment: rust threads are native threads for quite some time now. You don't have to do anything to use all the cores.

Comment: This is asking two **very** different questions. You should split them apart. Actually, it's 3 ("use all cores", `RTRACEMAXPROCS` and "800K threads").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust doesn't have green threads any more. Every "task" you spawn maps to exactly one real OS thread (which is why the task terminology has fallen out of favor completely). An equivalent of `GOMAXPROCS` doesn't make sense.

As for the second part of your question: 800K threads is ludicrous. It might work, but don't expect it to work nearly as well as Go's or Erlang's green threads. In particular, each thread reserves a couple of megabytes of address space and *at least* 4 KiB physical memory, plus whatever resources the OS needs for the thread (not a lot, I've been told). The "spawn concurrent workers for every little thing" paradigm is not very well supported.

Comment: I don't think the term `green threads` apply to Go since by definition, green threads are scheduled by a virtual machine. Go doesn't run on a VM.

Comment: @LeoCorrea The Wikipedia definition contrasts "scheduled by a VM" with "scheduled natively by the OS", so it can't mean VM in the traditional sense (and indeed the very same article lists Go as a language with green threads). I and most people I've talked to refer to most thread-like abstractions that are not managed by the OS as green threads.

Comment: @LeoCorrea, I think it is more correct to say that green threads are scheduled by runtime, not by a VM. "VMs" is a strict subset of "runtimes", and Go *does* have a runtime, as did Rust not so long ago.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Like many things "has a runtime" is a continuum and somewhat fuzzy. Current Rust still has infrastructure that could be called a runtime, just like C and C++ (assuming default configuration for all three). But yeah, it's much smaller and simpler and passive than Go's, or most languages'.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code of your source `RTRACEMAXPROCS` is not actually part of Rust but of the program being used in the example.

https://github.com/Byron/rust-tracer/blob/5f6008c6b3c97471d965ed3113be0b7d6800b289/src/rust/main.rs#L46-L53

The author is simply using that environment variable to create a thread pool of a specified size.

So short answer is No, `RTRACEMAXPROCS` and `GOMAXPROCS` are not the same thing.